# missing 1 required positional argument django _id

Tags: python, django

I'm trying make cart for delivery site. I've got a lot of problems) there one of them:

method remove() missing 1 argument:

my view:

```
def cart_remove(request, dish_id):
cart = Cart(request)
dish = get_object_or_404(Dish, id=dish_id)
cart_remove(dish)
return redirect('cart:cart_detail')
```

My template:

```
{% for item in cart%}
    {% with dish=item.dish %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{{ dish.get_absolute_url }}">
                    <img src="{{ dish.picture.url }}" width="100" height="100">
                </a>
            </td>
            <td>{{dish.name}}</td>
            <td>{{item.quantity}}</td>
            <td><a href="{% url 'cart:cart_remove' dish.id %}">Remove</a></td>
            <td class="num">$ {{item.price}} </td>
            <td class="num">$ {{item.total_price}} </td>
        </tr>
    {% endwith %}
{% endfor %}
```

my itter method in Cart class:

```
def __iter__(self):
    dish_ids = self.cart.keys()
    dishes = Dish.objects.filter(id__in=dish_ids)
    for dish in dishes:
        self.cart[str(dish.id)]['dish'] = dish

    for item in self.cart.values():
        item['price'] = Decimal(item['price'])
        item['total_price'] = item['price'] * item['quantity']
        yield item
```

my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('', cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
path('add/<dish_id>/', cart_add, name='cart_add'),
path('remove/<dish_id>/', cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
```

]

[My little error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEcRu.png)

Comment: Show us `urls.py`, you are most likely not specifying the `dish_id` argument there

Comment: urlpatterns = [
    path('', cart_detail, name='cart_detail'),
    path('add/<dish_id>/', cart_add, name='cart_add'),
    path('remove/<dish_id>/', cart_remove, name='cart_remove'),
]

Comment: the function needs correct indentation...

Comment: If you mean cart_remove, it correct in project, just pasting here like that